# CSS Display Textboxes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks to James Donnelly, this has been solved.  My example has been updated to the working solution.

My reputation isn't high enough so I can't post an image, so I am going to try and describe it as best as possible.  I have 7 textboxes and a textarea on a form, and when I load the page, it currently loads each textbox on a separate line.

However, I want the textboxes to load like this:
1 2 3
4 5 6 7
---8--- (span across)

Should I put each row inside a div?  I tried floating each textbox to the left, but that does not work correctly.  I have Twitter bootstrap setup in my project if that makes things easier.

Here is my working code:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>Enter Movie in System:</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-film"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { placeholder = "Title" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-facetime-video"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Director, new { placeholder = "Director" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Director)
        </div>

        @* Make dropdown *@
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tags"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.parentGenre, new { placeholder = "Genre" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.parentGenre)
        </div>  


        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stars, new { placeholder = "Actor" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Stars)
        </div>



        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration, new { placeholder = "Duration (mins)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
        </div>


    @* Make dropdown *@

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rating, new { placeholder = "Rating" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Rating)
        </div>



        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.releaseDate, new { placeholder = "Release Date" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.releaseDate)
        </div>


    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-comment"></i></span>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { placeholder = "Description", @class="input-xxlarge" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>
    </div>



        <p>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
        </p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this? http://jsfiddle.net/rRWdz/

Comment: Do you want me to get that setup?  It's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.content-group` is by default set to `display:table;` which is what's forcing each of your inputs down onto a new line. You'd simply need to put each of your `.input-prepend` containers into just one container:

```
    <div>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tags"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.parentGenre, new { placeholder = "Genre" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.parentGenre)
        </div>  

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tags"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.parentGenre, new { placeholder = "Genre" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.parentGenre)
        </div> 

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tags"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.parentGenre, new { placeholder = "Genre" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.parentGenre)
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u mean?

```
<div>
   <input id="tbx1" />
   <input id="tbx2" />
   <input id="tbx3" /><br />   
   <input id="tbx4" />
   <input id="tbx5" />
   <input id="tbx6" />
   <input id="tbx7" />
   <span id="span1" style="padding-left:200px">
      <input id="tbx8" />
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to post the css style you have tried.  but I am guessing that giving the form a float left, width and height should let you be able to float the input fields, make sure none of the first six inputs is greater than 30% of the form width. for the last one width 100%